# Issue with Chef / knife bootstrapping a Vagrant VM?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, bootstrapping, knife

I am trying to bootstrap a vagrant vm and install chef using the following command

```
knife bootstrap localhost -p 2222 -x vagrant -P vagrant --sudo
```

but nothing is happening - no error messages as seen in this paste bin - http://pastebin.com/06pyGAHZ please advice ? what am i missing ...

my vagrant file for reference - http://pastebin.com/djncyWNn

Update : 
i can try vagrant provision it might work. but what is puzzling to me is this

1) eventhough its a vagrant vm, it is no different , it has a ip address, i am able to ssh from local machine using ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2222

2) The knife statement is not giving any error message , it silently does nothing

Answer (score 1):

### To get this working update your Vagrantfile with a bridged network setting for the the VM.

db_config.vm.box = "Ubuntu12.04cloud"

### db_config.vm.network :bridged

This will bring the VM on your network and it won't be on a natted interface of Virtualbox, I am not sure why it does not work on the natted interface, but probably could be coz of Guest additions not up to date. Once done ssh to the box and check what is the bridged IP address and  if you have dns correctly setup you can update the FQDN for that box.

To bootstrap the Box use the FQDN pointing to the Bridged IP or use just the Bridged IP address. This sould work now.

Below is the output of aa ubuntu box i downloaded without Chef on it and boot strapped the Vagrant VM with the above mentioned method.

https://gist.github.com/vinitkhandagle/5164417

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative method to using knife to directly bootstrap your Vagrant VM's: Why not use the built in Vagrant Chef provisioner instead? In doing so, you don't need to install Chef on your Vagrant VM's, but you can still provision them with Chef.

Just under your Vagrant.configure("2") do |config| line, you can add it like this:

config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

  config.vm.define :oak do |oak|
    oak.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
    oak.vm.provision "chef_client" do |client|
      client.chef_server_url = "https://my-chef-server:443"
      client.validation_key_path = "/home/me/.chef/chef-validator.pem"
      client.add_role "base"
      client.add_recipe "users"
      client.add_recipe "nginx"
      client.environment = "development"
    end
  end

  config.vm.define :maple do |maple|
    ...
```